# Django Rest Framework ViewSet loses pagination, SearchFilter and OrderingFilter when overriding list() method

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have to override default `list()` method of a DRF ViewSet but, when I do so, all filtering, ordering and pagination stop working.

This is the code of the ViewSet:

```
class ZoneViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = models.Zone.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.ZoneSerializer
    filter_backends = (SearchFilter, OrderingFilter,)
    search_fields = ('city', 'name')

    def list(self, serializer, pk=None):
        if pk:
            queryset = models.Zone.objects.filter(city=pk)
        else:
            queryset = models.Zone.objects.all()
        serializer = serializers.ZoneSerializer(queryset, many=True, context={'request':self.request})
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

How can I override `list()` method without losing this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default `list()` method implements all these features. So instead of overriding `list` try override `get_queryset()` method. You can use `self.kwargs['pk']` to get `pk` value:

```
class ZoneViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = models.Zone.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.ZoneSerializer
    filter_backends = (SearchFilter, OrderingFilter,)
    search_fields = ('city', 'name')

    def get_queryset(self):
        pk = self.kwargs['pk']
        if pk:
            queryset = models.Zone.objects.filter(city=pk)
        else:
            queryset = models.Zone.objects.all()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried your advice, but I get this error: `pk = self.kwargs['pk']
KeyError: 'pk'`. I tried to catch the exception, but then I got this other error: `in get_count
    return len(queryset)
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()`.

Comment: @HugoLuisVillalobosCanto how you are passing `pk` to the view? Try `pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')` instead of `pk = self.kwargs['pk']`. This will catch KeyError in case `pk` is not in `kwargs`.

Comment: it works! I was missing to return the query set. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer does not work for me because my query set logic on listing breaks detail and delete endpoints. Instead I pasted the list implementation and tweaked the logic to my needs

```
class MyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):                                                                                
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)                                                                               
    serializer_class = MySerializer                                                                                    
    filter_fields = ["a_id", "b_id"]                                                                               

    def get_queryset(self):                                                                                               
        return My.objects.all()                                                                                        

    def list(self, request):                      
        # my custom query set logic                                                                                   
        a = self.request.query_params.get("a_id", None)                                                              
        b = self.request.query_params.get("b_id", None)                                                          
        if a is None and b is None:                                                                                
            queryset = My.objects.none()                                                                               
        else:                                                                                                             
            queryset = My.objects.all()
        # end custom                                                                                

        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)                                                                           
        if page is not None:                                                                                              
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)                                                             
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)                                                           

        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)                                                             
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

See http://www.cdrf.co/3.9/rest_framework.viewsets/ModelViewSet.html

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to override anything if you need to filter against a `pk`. Instead, the `retrieve` view set action should be used: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#viewset-actions.

Anyone in this situation should reconsider their API implementation before getting into a rabbit hole.

However, if you **must** override the `list` view set action, consider overriding just that, not the `get_queryset` on which all other actions depend. And to keep pagination and search in place, follow the original mixin implementation: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py#L33.